# How can I create a number of pyqt5 widgets where the number depends on the amount of lines in a file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a python web browser using pyqt5. In that directory I also have a file called bookmarks.json which has all the bookmarks stored. I have made the widgets appear with the correct name, but the urls always go to the last bookmark. What i mean is that if i click on Gmail it will go to google search. What i have tried is making different variable names. Thank you for any help in further advance!
bookmarks.json:
`{ "Gmail": "http://mail.google.com/u/0", "Google Search": "http://google.com" }`
my code:
`bookmarks = self.read_bookmarks() for bookmark_name in bookmarks: bookmark_url = bookmarks[bookmark_name] bookmark_btn = QAction(bookmark_name, self) bookmark_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.add_new_tab(bookmark_url))         self.bookmark_bar.addAction(bookmark_btn)`
read_bookmarks function:
`def read_bookmarks(self): return json.load(open("bookmarks.json"))`

What i have tried is making different variable names and debugging everything by printing what the aim is (eg. the output dictionary of read_bookmarks).

Comment: `bookmark_btn.triggered.connect(lambda _, url=bookmark_url: self.add_new_tab(url))`